RSA finding plaintext just not knowing the decryption key
Studying RSA i stumbled upon this one,
not knowing
N = 237540380304900134239
C = 226131284405640469226
e = 2^16+1
(RSA Encryption: m^e mod N | Decryption: C^d mod N)
Any external tool should not be used.
We have to find the message m. However we need d, to get that we need to know the totion of n, so factorization of n is a must or is it? How do I proceed from here? Any help is appreciated.

$N$ has $\log_2(N) \approx 67.8 \leq 70$. So, essentially any (computer-based) method of factorizing $N$ should work well. For example, trial division (generally "hopeless" for cryptographically relevant parameters) should take $O(\sqrt{N})$ operations, or $\approx 2^{35}$ arithmetic operations on $\approx 70$ bit numbers.
This is very reasonable to do on something like a desktop computer.
Provided

Any external tool should not be used.

does not preclude you implementing your own stuff, you should be able to

factor $N$ using trial division, then
compute $\varphi(N) = \varphi(pq) = (p-1)(q-1)$, and finally
compute $d = e^{-1}\bmod (p-1)(q-1)$ using the euclidean algorithm.

I imagine you have the above "sketched" plan, and were just wondering if step 1 was feasible. As the first part of this answer explains, it should be.
To verify, I just did a "very stupid" implementation of trial division, namely
import math
from tqdm import tqdm

def trial_division(N):
    sqrt_N = math.ceil(math.sqrt(N))
    factors = []
    while N % 2 == 0:
        factors.append(2)
        N //= 2
    for i in tqdm(range(3, sqrt_N, 2)):
        while N % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            N //= i
        if N == 1:
            return factors
    factors.append(N)
    return factors

Here, tqdm is a standard python utility for estimating the running time of a loop. Note dividing out by $2$ first, and then looping over only odd numbers. This is a (relatively important) trivial optimization, which gives a $\approx 2\times$ speedup.
There are other speedups available, for example parallelization, or using a faster language.
I did both, with three implementations here (the above Python, the Rust equivalent, and a parallelized Rust equivalent).
This led to running times



Implementation
Time (s)




Serial Python
908


Serial Rust
20.86


Parallel Rust
10.81



So, doing the above, perhaps in a faster language than Python, is already fine.
Note that the machine that was tested has 4 cores. I ran the same numbers on a 12 core machine, and the parallelized code factored $N$ in ~2.5s.

Due to how most Python interpreters do integer math, a loop's duration will abruptly get slower (by like +60%) for i past $2^{30}$, and the vast majority of the time will be spent over that limit, thus I think the 26 minutes estimate is significantly optimistic. In the context we can stop at the first factor, but N is such that this saving is relatively minor.

The best known general attack is to factor $N$, then proceed to decryption as in textbook RSA.
Trial division works at cost $\mathcal O(N^{1/2})$ and that can be minutes for the 68-bit $N$ at hand (see that other answer). So I suggest Pollard's rho that can have cost $\mathcal O(N^{1/4})$.
The following Python program solves the problem in a fraction of a second, and remains below a minute for most 96-bit $N$. It uses Pollard's rho, retrying with a different polynomial when it fails or takes more iterations than we hope for (this strategy makes it hard to find pathological cases). For simplicity, the RSA part assumes $N$ is the product of two distinct prime factors. Try It Online!
## Given a positive composite N, return a divisor of N at least 2.
## Duration grows very roughly as the square root of the smallest
## prime factor of N, times some small power of log(N).
## If N is prime or below 2, return None (that case is very slow).
def PollardRho(N:int)->int:
    s = 2 # s is 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21...
    while s*s<=N:
        x = y = 1 # such that that first g is s
        for _ in range(3<<(N.bit_length()>>2)):
            y = (y*y+s)%N
            g = y-x
            if g==0: break # failure, try another s
            # next 2 lines compute  g = GCD(N, g)
            (g, h) = (N, N%(-g if g<0 else g))
            while h!=0: (g, h) = (h, g%h)
            if g!=1: return g # success
            x = (x*x+s)%N
            y = (y*y+s)%N
        s += (s&1)+1
    return None

## Solve an RSA problem with N the product of two distinct primes.
(N, C, e) = (237540380304900134239, 226131284405640469226, 2**16+1)
try:
    p = PollardRho(N)
    q = N//p
    print("N =",N,"=",p,"*",q)
    M = pow(C, pow(e, -1, (p-1)*(q-1)), N)
    if pow(M,e,N)!=C: raise
    print("M =",M,"=",hex(M))
except:
    print("Failure")

Note: There are much faster (but more complex) factorization algorithms, including Pollard's p-1, Lenstra's ECM, MPQS, GNFS.

For this i will find the two Factor of N and using lenstra algo to factorize.
After you get the two Factor you ré able
To decrypt m.
